GLX problem with Xming, WSL2 and SSH
I have Ubuntu 22.04 running on WSL2 in my Windows 11, and I am connecting to another Ubuntu 22.04 in my LAN from the WSL2 with SSH. I want to display a GUI on my Windows from the remote PC. I have installed Xming in my Windows and I added the IP address of the remote PC to the host list. I also added the IP address of my Windows PC as a DISPLAY of the remote PC.
But when I ran my test script to open Mujoco, I got the following error:
user@remote-pc-name:~/Documents$ python3 temp_test_mujoco.py
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/glfw/__init__.py:914: GLFWError: (65542) b'GLX: GLX version 1.3 is required'
  warnings.warn(message, GLFWError)
ERROR: could not create window

Press Enter to exit ...

I don't know where I should look for the GLX, if it's on Windows, the WSL2 or the remote PC.
For the WSL2, I have the version 1.4, so it should be fine:
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4

For the remote PC, even after using sudo apt install mesa-utils, GLX is not found:
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

For Windows, I don't know where to look (and if I should look on Windows).
How to make the remote GUI work in my situation to run Mujoco?
I can run other GUI applications from my WSL2 directly without problems (like gedit test.txt), and from SSH. But not Mujoco which requires GLX.

See if exporting LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1 to the client environment helps e.g. LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1 python3 temp_test_mujoco.py

Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, it is not working (still the same error).
